# Cauchy integral formula over a squared root

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Show:
$\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}$ $\int_C \dfrac{e^{kz}}{(z^2+1)^2} \,dz = \frac12 \sin (k) - \frac k2 \cos (k)$

where $k > 0$ and $C$ is the circle with center $0$ and radius $2$ traversed in the anti-clockwise direction.

I have tried cauchy integral formula where $z≠\sqrt{-1}$

But it did not yield the correct result.

Comment: First determine your poles then find the residues!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Use partial fraction expansion to write

$$\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2}=\frac{i/4}{z+i}-\frac{1/4}{(z+i)^2}-\frac{i/4}{z-i}-\frac{1/4}{(z-i)^2} \tag 1$$

Then, proceed by applying [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) separately to the four resulting terms.  Alternatively, apply the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).

---

**SPOILER ALERT:**  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution.

> From $(1)$, we can write $$\begin{align}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{e^{kz}}{(z^2+1)^2}\,dz&=\frac14 \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{ie^{kz}}{z+i}\,dz-\frac14 \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{|z|=2}\frac{e^{kz}}{(z+i)^2}\,dz\\\\&-\frac14 \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{|z|=2}\frac{ie^{kz}}{z-i}\,dz-\frac14 \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{|z|=2}\frac{e^{kz}}{(z-i)^2}\,dz\\\\&=\frac14\left(ie^{-ik}-ke^{-ik}-ie^{ik}-ke^{ik}\right)\\\\&=\frac12 \sin(k)-\frac k2 \cos(k)\end{align}$$as was to be shown!